# how to solve this query into join query

Tags: mysql

my colleague want me to change this query

```
UPDATE user_sesi a SET   
a.`soal_start`= (SELECT waktu_buat FROM cc_soal_aja b WHERE b.`class_id`=a.`class_id` AND b.`id_modul`=a.`modul_id` AND b.`id_sesi`=a.`id_sesi` AND b.`created_by`=a.`user_id` ORDER BY b.`soal_konter` DESC LIMIT 1);
```

2183 row(s) affected

into join query , i already try but the result always different with first query

```
UPDATE user_sesi a
JOIN 
(
    SELECT waktu_buat,class_id,id_modul,id_sesi,created_by
    FROM cc_soal_aja 
    ORDER BY soal_konter DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) a14
ON a14.`class_id`=a.`class_id` AND 
a14.`id_modul`=a.`modul.id` AND 
a14.`id_sesi`=a.`id_sesi` AND 
a14.`created_by`=a.`user_id`
SET a.soal_start=a14.created_time
```

1 row(s) affected

can someone tell me what i missing , thanks for help

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure a regular update join will work the way you want here.  But, we might be able to use `ROW_NUMBER`, if you are using MySQL 8+:

```sql
UPDATE user_sesi a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY waktu_buat, class_id, id_modul, id_sesi,
                                              created_by
                                 ORDER BY soal_konter DESC) rn
    FROM cc_soal_aja 
) a14
    ON a14.class_id = a.class_id AND
       a14.id_modul = a.modul.id AND
       a14.id_sesi = a.id_sesi AND
       a14.created_by = a.user_id
SET
    soal_start = a14.created_time
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I was unaware of ROW_NUMBER. Would this be as fast as creating a temporary table then doing the join?

Comment: @MarshallC No, the temporary table approach (which is really like a materialized view) would probably be faster, especially if we indexed that table appropriately.  Actually, I'm not even sure if my answer satisfy the OP, but it is my hunch based on what I did see.